# I can't load image to tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, label, dice

[image]I try to add image of dice to ma dice simulator but when i try to add image of it to my label, the label shrinks and image isn't there.

code is following(I hope you'll understand mi shitty coding style lol):

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = Tk(className="dice simulator")
window.geometry("600x600")

picture_open = Image.open(r"/home/dan/dice1.png")
picture_resize = picture_open.resize((200, 200))
picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(picture_resize)


def throw():
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    if number == 1:
        dice["image"] = picture


background = Label(window, bg="#000000", height=60, width=80)
background.pack()
background.pack_propagate(0)

buttonx1 = Button(window, text="throw 1x", command=throw)
buttonx1.pack()
buttonx1.pack_propagate(0)
buttonx1.place(x=255, y=475)

dice = Label(window, height=12, width=20, bg="#ffffff")
dice.pack()
dice.pack_propagate(0)
dice.place(x=220, y=150)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried many things as you can see I set the height and width for the label and I use pack_propagate function but it still doesn't work how it should:D

I recommend you to try to run it and I hope you'll understand everything, if not I will try to answer all questions:) Thanks for any answer

Stackoverflow still says  that my post is mostly code and i dont know what more should i write here lol, I hope that will be enough.

I tried to make in smaller and it appeared in the label but the label got much smaller so the problem is shrinking of label

Comment: If you are going to call `.place`, then there is no need for the `.pack` on that widget. Also `.pack_propagate` only makes sense when you call it on a window or a frame

Comment: there is a slight problem, this: _I recommend you to try to run it_ is pretty impossible since we don't have the image, also I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: wait a second, there is a random number gen? how do you know that the image doesn't appear, maybe `number` has never been equal to 1 so the if statement fails, also I can sense that you will have at least 6 if/elif statements, so I suggest you use a dictionary and store images there and then simply access in a similar fashion to this: `dice['image'] = image_dct[number]` and then you don't need any if statements, just a dictionary which will be easier to organize and expand

Comment: @mattis try to run it the label shrinks a lot when 1 appears, the code is absolutely incomplete because i stopped here. Btw do u think that problem with the import could solve it or it's just by the way? anyways it's pretty useful I just use * because i dont know lol

Comment: ok, I think I already mentioned, but I don't have that picture (ok, will try with another)

Comment: thise is the image btw:D I tried to make it smaller and it appeared in the label but the label got much smaller so the problem is shrinking of label

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the issue (among other "issues" with your code (some of which I have already mentioned)), you set `width` and `height` for the label, while there is no image, those numbers are treated as characters of the font size and stuff, when you assign an image, those are treated as pixels so the easiest would be to remove `width` and `height` arguments from the `Label`, leave it like this (the simplest option):

```py
dice = Label(window, bg="#ffffff")
```

Overall I would suggest these improvements (just compare to your code):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = Tk(className="dice simulator")
window.geometry("600x600")

picture_open = Image.open(r"pause_btn.png")
picture_resize = picture_open.resize((200, 200))
picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(picture_resize)


def throw():
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    if number == 1:
        dice.config(image=picture)


background = Label(window, bg="#000000")
background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

buttonx1 = Button(window, text="throw 1x", command=throw)
buttonx1.place(x=255, y=475)

dice = Label(window, bg="#ffffff")
dice.place(x=220, y=150)

window.mainloop()
```

Quickly go over:

- Don't use `.<manager>_propagate()` on sth that is not a frame or a window
- Use only one layout manager per widget
- I added how to add a proper background image  (for this case at least, notice the use of `relwidth` and `relheight` and other things in that `.place()` method)
- Added the solved current issue

---

**EDIT 1:** I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

**EDIT 2:** this is how I would suggest storing images for this case:

```py
image_dct = {1: picture_1, 2: picture_2}
```

Then you can access them like so:

```py
def throw():
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice['image'] = image_dct[number]
```

(beware key errors if you haven't yet completed the dictionary)

Another fancy thing would be to do sth like this:

```py
image_dct = {key: ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(value).resize((200, 200))) for key, value 
             in enumerate([f'path/to/image_{img_number}' for img_number in range(amount_of_images)])}
```

---

As @TheLizzard suggested you can also use tuples (since they are faster, less space consuming and there isn't really a need to modify these):

```py
image_list = tuple(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image).resize((200, 200))) for image 
                   in (f"path/to/image_{img_number}" for img_number in range(amount_of_images)))
```

Another small note about `tuples`: for accessing you could use sth like this:

```py
def throw():
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice['image'] = image_list[number - 1] # -1 because first item has index 0 and the range starts from 1
```

---

and here you would store all images in one place (directory) and all of them would be named like so (as an example) (change the range accordingly of what is the first image name):

"image_1"
"image_2"
"image_3"

and that would make it very easy to add all of those image at runtime to the dictionary and assign the correct keys to them, making it super easy to add more images and stuff

If you have any questions, be sure to ask

Comment: @DanŠafránek edited question to add some more info and stuff, also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if the answer helped you , that is to help future readers and to allow marking other questions as duplicates with this one

Comment: @Matiiss Why not use a `tuple` instead of a `dict` for storing the images. If you do that you can use list comprehension as well. Also `tuple`s take up less space and have faster look up time (if I am not mistaken). Basically: `image_list = tuple(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image).resize((200, 200))) for image in (f"path/to/image_{img_number}" for img_number in range(amount_of_images)))`. Also I would advice splitting it in 2 lines

Comment: @TheLizzard well I like dictionaries better that is why I use them, for this case (unless there was a dice with like a couple billion sides) the look up times don't really make a difference (and you are probably right that they are faster for tuples), the only thing I kinda don't like is that you can't change tuples (as if it were needed anyways in this case because all images are preloaded), so might as well use those (I just prefer dicts) but btw how do you use list comprehension on dicts? (oh this: `tuple([here goes the list comprehension])`?) agree about the two lines (PEP 8 and 72 chars)

Comment: Instead of `tuple([here goes the list comprehension])` use `tuple(here goes the list comprehension)`. That way it doesn't have to built a `list` that is converted to a `tuple`. Also if you have a set number of items that you aren't/can't change, it's better to use `tuple`s. If you need to change the size/items, use a `list`. If the key isn't going to be an integer (something like a string), it's best to use a `dict`.

Comment: @Matiiss If you want to have some fun compare the result of: `from dis import dis; dis("tuple([i for i in range(10)])")` vs `from dis import dis; dis("tuple(i for i in range(10))")`. It's fun to use the `dis` library to see how python interprets your code.